# How to get SQL query being executed from af:search?

Tags: sql, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a page where I have implemented an af:query and a result table. The problem is that I can't retrieve within a managed bean method the exact query that is used at runtime by this component.
Is there any way to get the query string that is being executed within the af:query component?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here https://community.oracle.com/thread/3516102 I have to override the executeQueryForCollection(), and, before super call, I can  print out the result of getQuery() method.

The detailed solution is explained here: [Get SQL Query and Parameters from af:search](http://adfgok.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/get-sql-query-and-parameters-from-afsearch/)